What is the best way to guarantee no boot loops after rooting android 7 tecno tablet?
I have located a firmware package of my tablet brand. It also has the same build number. The variant number is also identical to mine. I extracted the zip file and got a boot image. Now reassure myself all was going to be ok; I tried to open it on win 10 PC. The PC, responded with an error message. "The file is corrupt." I have not installed it and am hesitant to use it. Thus, my question above. I intend to use ADB to and Magisk. I have no recovery TWRP for my build and brand tablet.

That Windows can not open Android firmware image is totally normal. Only OTA firmware images are delivered as ZIP file, the other image formats are proprietary or base on Linux file-systems Windows can not handle.
